# Convert ascii codes(integers) to characters

Tags: c

I am trying to convert a list of integers to characters (integers are separated by white spaces, newlines and tabs). The input ends with EOF. For example, 
input;
72 101 108 108 111 44
32 119 111 114 108 100 33
output
Hello, world!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAXBUFFERSIZE   100

void cleartoendofline( void );  /* ANSI function prototype */

void cleartoendofline( void )
{
    char ch;
        ch != '\n';
    //ch = getchar();
    //while( ch != '\n' )
        //ch = getchar();
}

main()
{
    char    ch;                     /* handles user input */
    char    buffer[MAXBUFFERSIZE];  /* sufficient to handle one line */
    int     char_count;             /* number of characters read for this line */
    int     exit_flag = 0;
    int     valid_choice;

    while( exit_flag  == 0 ) {
        printf("Enter integer(s)\n: ");
        //ch = getchar();
                scanf("%d",&ch)
        char_count = 0;
        while( (ch != '\n')  &&  (char_count < MAXBUFFERSIZE)) {
            buffer[char_count++] = ch;
            ch = getchar();
        }
        buffer[char_count] = 0x00;      /* null terminate buffer */
        printf("\nIntegers translates to:\n");
        printf("%s\n", buffer);

        valid_choice = 0;
        while( valid_choice == 0 ) {
            printf("Continue (Y/N)?\n");
            scanf(" %c", &ch );
            ch = toupper( ch );
            if((ch == 'Y') || (ch == 'N') )
                valid_choice = 1;
            else
                printf("\007Error: Invalid choice\n");
            cleartoendofline();
        }
        if( ch == 'N' ) exit_flag = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks Eric, I wasn't aware of the homework tag

Comment: "That's nice". So, what "doesn't work"? And how? Does it SEGV? Does it not stop asking for input? Does it spit out the wrong value? Is it just not implemented to do "the task" yet? That is: **What is the question?**

Comment: it just returns the same string as output. I have tried to use %d to no avail

Comment: You read a string of characters into your buffer and then `printf("%s\n", buffer);`.  What exactly are you expecting to happen besides printing the same string of characters as you read in?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out indiv, I will edit the code.

Comment: You're using `scanf` to expect an integer, but read into a character. Also, when you convert 97 into 'a' or whatever, don't assume the characters are consecutive like they are in ASCII, or that ASCII is even being used. Check out EBCDIC for an example of that.

Comment: Your `cleartoendofline` function does nothing, and why need a prototype when the definition was already before calling place. No need for `while( exit_flag  == 0 ) {... if( ch == 'N' ) exit_flag = 1;    }` too, just `while (1) {... if (ch == 'N') return; }` is enough. Also, '\a' would be much easier to read than '\007'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed e.g

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAXBUFFERSIZE   100

void cleartoendofline( void );  /* ANSI function prototype */

void cleartoendofline( void ){
    while('\n'!=getchar());
}

main(){
    char    ch;                     /* handles user input delimiter*/
    int     num;                    /* user input number */
    char    buffer[MAXBUFFERSIZE];  /* sufficient to handle one line */
    int     char_count;             /* number of characters read for this line */
    int     exit_flag = 0;
    int     valid_choice;

    while( exit_flag  == 0 ) {
        printf("Enter integer(s)\n: ");
        scanf(" %d%c", &num, &ch);//read integer and delimiter
        char_count = 0;
        while( char_count < MAXBUFFERSIZE - 1) {//-1 for End of string
            buffer[char_count++] = (char)num;
            if(ch == '\n')break;
            scanf("%d%c", &num, &ch);
        }
        buffer[char_count] = 0x00;      /* null terminate buffer */
        printf("\nIntegers translates to:\n");
        printf("%s\n", buffer);

        valid_choice = 0;
        while( valid_choice == 0 ) {
            printf("Continue (Y/N)?\n");
            scanf(" %c", &ch );
            ch = toupper( ch );
            if((ch == 'Y') || (ch == 'N') )
                valid_choice = 1;
            else
                printf("\aError: Invalid choice\n");
            cleartoendofline();
        }
        if( ch == 'N' ) exit_flag = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Learn the difference between `scanf` and `getchar()`, especially when they are presented with the same input.

Read the documentation for `scanf` very, very carefully—there's a lot going on.

You might learn the most by writing your own specialized routine instead of calling `scanf()`.  It's usually poor practice to duplicate functionality that is in the C standard, but it's OK if the goal is to help you learn.